# Does function returning only value as object from ConcurrentHashMap<K,V> need to be synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a below class:

```
Class GameDataHandler {
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<Long, GameData> m_lstUpcomingGameData = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public GameDataHandler () {
       s_instance = this;
    }


    public static IGameData GetGameDataById(long a_gameId) {
        return s_instance.m_lstUpcomingGameData.get(a_gameId);
    }    
}
```

In my case, `GetGameDataById()` function is being called by multiple threads. Do I need to put `synchronized` on my method?

I know that the ConcurrentHashMap is thread-safe, but I am not sure about `GetGameDataById()` function itself.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need that. Make it `synchronized` leads to only one thread can execute the method at the same time, that does not make sense.

But you might need remove the static modifier of method `GetGameDataById` since the `Map` is non-static.